# How can I tell if a device supports Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: wireless-networking

For example, how can I tell if a WiFi adapter supports WiFi Direct?

Is there any standard that makes it explicit that WiFi Direct is supported? I see devices support 802.11ac or 802.11n, but not sure if they will allow me to communicate through WiFi Direct.

Answer (score 4):

The Wi-Fi Alliance owns the trademark "Wi-Fi CERTIFIED Wi-Fi Direct®", and only licenses companies to use it on products that have been certified compatible by the Wi-Fi Alliance.

So look to make sure the product is on this list:
http://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?capabilities=3

More information here:
http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct

Comment: I don't think every product that supports the standard goes through certification. I wish there was another way to know if a device supports Wi-Fi Direct. E.g., I am in the process of buying Wi-Fi adapters such as [this one](http://amzn.com/B003E6493G) and it is not in the list, in fact non of the adapters listed in Amazon are in the Wi-Fi list.

Comment: @kiewic Wi-Fi Direct is a tricky standard to implement and easy to get wrong. If you care about having support for it, I highly recommend you stick to the devices that care enough about quality to pass the compliance certification testing program.

Comment: Looks like this particular certification is now gone on that wifi alliance search page ... miracast is there though

Comment: @matt It's no longer a "featured" certification, but if you click on the Advanced Filters you can still find it. I believe that *Wi-Fi Aware* has replaced Wi-Fi Direct as being the Wi-Fi Alliance's favored peer-to-peer protocol.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a standard way of knowing if a device supports WiFi-Direct but if you go to the command prompt and type in `ipconfig /all` and scroll around a bit you will see a device with the description of "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter".
[image]

If you see that then there will be support, but without testing it on a computer first there is no way of knowing if something supports it or not, at least not at the time of writing maybe it will be on the back of the back when buying a Wi-Fi device in the future.

Hope this helped :)

Source: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/wifi-direct-vs-bluetooth-use-sharing-data-windows-8/

Comment: For a quick overview of network interfaces in the system, `ipconfig /all | findstr Description` is great. No need to sift throught the long dump to get the information.